# new template in wordpress is not displayed under page attributes -> template

Tags: php, wordpress

i want to integrate several layouts into my theme. so far I have solved it via page.php and page-blue.php because I saw it that way in tutorials. unfortunately the other template is not displayed under the page attributes. i don't see the error. even if i choose a different theme the attributes do not appear. what am I doing wrong?

> it should look like this

[image: it should look like this]

> this is how it looks

[image: this is how it looks]

> this is the page.php

[image: this is the page.php]

> this is the page-blue.php

[image: this is the page-blue.php]

Answer (score 2):

Change the name of the template, `page` is reserved word, also create brand-new file with file name other than `page.php`, which is also reserved file name.
And, for god's sake, name your template files in a way they mean something, self-explanatory.

Example for dummies:

```
<?php
/*
* Template Name: Some Template
*/
```

And the file name of the template should be `some-template.php` **inside your** theme's folder!

[Read more](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/)

Answer (score 1):

pls Use This code

```
<?php
/*
* Template Name: page-blue
* Template Post Type: post
*/
get_header();
?>
```

instead of this

```
<?php
/*
* Template Name: page-blue
*/
get_header();
?>
```

Comment: This code will work when you are creating a template for posts, cause I think you are creating a template for posts but you register it only for pages.